# How to create a .war archive for jenkins artifacts

Tags: jenkins, war, devops, artifacts

I'm running a code review project in jenkins and trying to archive the artifacts that are generated into a **.war** file.

Instead it is generating the artifacts as **.zip** file in jenkins

[image: after generating artifacts]

I tried searching a lot. But nothing is very helpful.

Is there any workaround to generate artifacts as **.war** file instead of **.zip**.

Am I doing this correctly?  Or please can anyone explain the step-4 if that is what I'm doing.

[image: steps that I followed]

Comment: Is this for your amazing DevOps engineer application?

Comment: Yes. For DevOps application only. Any idea of how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Would say you should learn a bit of Jenkins and related tools. Then this shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Chenmunka, please stop suggesting trivial edits to simply gain rep. If you wish to participate please do so by providing quality content.

Answer (score 0):

Archives, when configured relative to $WORKSPACE are generated in a .zip file only. If your generated o/p is a .war file and you are archiving the same, then it will be a .war file inside .zip file.

Can you put more details about what are the generated artifacts are and why they are needed as .war only? As well as what are you going to do with .war? Deploying anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

It pretty straight forward. Look at the screenshots to configure the same.

[image]

[image]